# How to define %>% operator?

Tags: r

I need another operator with the same functions as magrittr's  %>%.

I tried

```
"%myop%" <- function(x,f) do.call(f, list(x))
```

but it doesn't work.

I expect to get my function on the right side solved with the argument from left side, e.g:

```
> p<-10
> p %>% log()
[1] 2.302585
```

which is x %>% f and can be rewritten as f(x)

x %>% f(a,b) which can be rewritten as f(x,a,b) -- and this doesn't work

How can I define it?

Comment: What is your infix supposed to do and how does it fail?

Comment: Seems like a typo. Works for me with back ticks instead of quotes. `back_tick%myop% back_tick <- function(x,f) do.call(f, list(x));
iris[-5] %myop% sum`

Comment: it's supposed to have the same purpose like %>%.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, I get  "Error in x[a, ] : incorrect number of dimensions" when I try to use it with matrices

Comment: Could you edit the question with sample data and expected behavior?

Comment: This seems to work for me `p %myop% log`. You don't need to call `log()` since `do.call`'s `what` uses a string not the function itself.

Comment: that is correct, I edited my question one more time

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't use `magrittr::\`%>%\``?

Comment: my homework is to define it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the [magrittr implementation](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/blob/master/R/pipe.R) but, to be fair, the code is quite complex since it does a lot more.

Simply put, to support the semantics you desire you need to extract the unevaluated RHS of the expression and insert the unevaluated LHS into it before evaluating it.

A function call expression is a list that has the function name as its first element, and the rest of its arguments as subsequent elements. So you need to insert the LHS value into that list at the second position.

You then need to turn the resulting list back into a call — `as.call` does that:

```
`%>%` = function (lhs, rhs) {
    lhs = substitute(lhs)
    rhs = substitute(rhs)

    if (is.name(rhs)) {
        do.call(as.character(rhs), list(lhs))
    } else if (is.call(rhs)) {
        rhs = as.list(rhs)
        call = as.call(c(rhs[[1L]], list(lhs), rhs[-1L]))
        eval.parent(call)
    } else {
        stop('Unsupported RHS')
    }
}
```

Beware that, since this implementation inserts the *unevaluated* LHS into the RHS call, a chained pipeline will be evaluated right-to-left. That is, this

```
(1 : 5) %>% sapply(`*`, 2) %>% sum()
```

will be transformed into this:

```
sum(sapply((1: 5), `*`, 2))
```

before any component is being evaluated.